# set values in dataframe based on columns in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['X','Y','Z'])
```

I can easily set the values in df to zero if they are less than a constant:

```
df[df < 0.0] = 0.0
```

can someone tell me how to instead compare to a column in a different dataframe?  I assumed this would work, but it does not:

```
df[df < df2.X] = 0.0
```

Comment: Are you wanting to compare column or row-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need to use [`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html#pandas.DataFrame.lt) and pass `axis=0` to compare column-wise:

```
In [83]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['X','Y','Z'])
df

Out[83]:
          A         B         C
0  2.410659 -1.508592 -1.626923
1 -1.550511  0.983712 -0.021670
2  1.295553 -0.388102  0.091239
3  2.179568  2.266983  0.030463
4  1.413852 -0.109938  1.232334

In [87]:
df2

Out[87]:
          X         Y         Z
0  0.267544  0.355003 -1.478263
1 -1.419736  0.197300 -1.183842
2  0.049764 -0.033631  0.343932
3 -0.863873 -1.361624 -1.043320
4  0.219959  0.560951  1.820347

In [86]:
df[df.lt(df2.X, axis=0)] = 0
df

Out[86]:
          A         B         C
0  2.410659  0.000000  0.000000
1  0.000000  0.983712 -0.021670
2  1.295553  0.000000  0.091239
3  2.179568  2.266983  0.030463
4  1.413852  0.000000  1.232334
```